# How can I have Visual Studio copy nlog.config to Application.exe.nlog?

Tags: nlog

I'm using Visual Studio Community 2022 Version 17.4.0 Preview 2.1. If I use the build action Content for nlog.config, it copies a file named nlog.config to the output. If I rename the file to MyApp.exe.nlog, it doesn't copy it to the output and NLog.Schema doesn't work.

How can I cause visual studio to copy nlog.config to Application.exe.nlog to the output? In NLog 5, this is the first place a config file is looked for.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what changed, but creating application.exe.nlog, using build action Content and copy if newer, results in the file being copied to the output, when the project is built.